# checkbox dynamic create for jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How do i create multiple checkbox for jquery to identify it?

example i have a html page with
this is call new.html

```
<div id =new> <input type=checkbox"></div>
```

at create.html
i want to use jquery to load multiple checkbox

```
<div id=load> <div>
$("#load).load(new.html)
```

so if i use a for loop to loop 10times to create 10 checkbox, how do i identify each checkbox uniquely?

```
for(var i = 0;i<10;i++){
$("#load).load(new.html)}
```

Comment: 1) Loading 10 times is not the right way - why load at all? If you must, do it once then cache from there. 2) Why do you need to uniquely identify them at all? You may be looking for classes instead of IDs.

Comment: \i am doing dynamic checkbox i dont know how many user want. user can choose 10 20 100 300 500.

Comment: That's fine, but you shouldn't load them each time, and giving them unique IDs seems pointless unless there's something else you're not saying.

Comment: there a group of element with a checkbox. user can select any number of time to load this set of element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them unique id, cache your markup in a variable and append everything at last for best performance.

```
var inputs = [], i
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  inputs.push('<input type="checkbox" id="ck'+ i +'"/>')
$('#load').append(inputs.join(''))
```

**Edit:**
Helper function:

```
var makeCkBoxes = function (n) {
  var inputs = [], i
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    inputs.push('<input type="checkbox" id="ck'+ i +'"')
  return inputs.join('')  
}

$('#load').append(makeCkBoxes(10))
```

Comment: if i have 2 set of checkbox 10 10 so i append a div infront of the 2 set ?

Comment: Just create a helper function where you pass a number and it returns the markup. See edit

Comment: can i push('new.html') in it?